# Did the review counter just start showing total counts?

Tags: support, review

Clicking the orange review counter used to take me right to suggested edits. As of sometime in the past couple days, it started showing the total number of waiting reviews (not just edits), and leading to /review.

When was this changed, and why? It's not on [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is on that page. Specifically, around April of this year, there's the following entry:

> •2014-04-29: 10K users now see the total number of pending review tasks in the top bar instead of just pending suggested edits.

Congratulations on passing 10K on Stack Overflow!

Comment: But that happened just before i reached 10k, i think. :/

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mean, it seems like it started showing total counts just before i hit 10k. I only hit 10k yesterday.

Comment: @Scimonster: you reached 10k yesterday; you cannot have seen the counter change before that time. The counter functionality hasn't changed recently, certainly.