# What does the review counter indicate when you have the 10k tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I have the 10k tools on a site (a private beta, so 1k), and when I got it, the review counter suddenly changed. It went from showing suggested edits to something else much larger.

[image]

What does this represent now? Note it isn't all queues together:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. . . This is a dup, I think. The number states the overall reviews need to be done in the site.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani see the edit

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244173/did-the-review-counter-just-start-showing-total-counts

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it

Comment: Okay, I'll use adblock on it then :P

Comment: See also: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/the-change-to-the-taskbar-is-massively-annoying/5763#5763